# C++: Extracting value from linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

This code crashes when I call `extractMin()` more than once. I think it should be obvious to
some of you where the problem lies in the function since I am new to pointers and is probably an obvious bug. So it should be enough that you know it´s a linked list without going into detail other than the function is supposed to retrieve the lexicographical smallest value using the `<` operator, and then delete that value from the linked list.

```
string LinkedListPQueue::extractMin() {
    if (this->isEmpty()) throw ErrorException("Empty queue.");
    string front = LEX_HIGH;
    cell *old;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++) {
        if (this->head->value < front) {
            front = this->head->value;
            old = this->head;
        }

        old = this->head;
        this->head = this->head->next;
    }

    logSize--;
    delete old;
    return front;
}



void LinkedListPQueue::enqueue(const string& elem) {
    cell *newCell = new cell;
    newCell->value = elem;
    newCell->next = NULL;
    if(this->isEmpty()) {
        this->head = this->tail = newCell;
        logSize++;

    } else {
        recurSort(newCell);
        this->tail->next = newCell;
        this->tail = newCell;
        logSize++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Why aren't you using STL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the head member in `extractMin()`, which leaves the list broken.

Comment: Well not completely true. The problem is he is modifying head in a incorrect way. Otherwise the function being extract, should remove an element and thus should also modify head.

Answer (score 1):

Your `head` gets modified but never reset after the run

You should simply use `iterators` or simply add a pointer that starts at `head` and move this pointer around instead of "breaking" your list's `head`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++) {
    if (this->head->value < front) {
        front = this->head->value;
        old = this->head;
    }

    old = this->head;
    this->head = this->head->next;
}
```

It seems obsolete to me, but it also causes memory leak as well as results in the list having a single element after its execution.

Seems to me these two lines:

```
old = this->head;
this->head = this->head->next;
```

Should not be in the cycle. The function logic should be a bit more complex - you find a pointer to the minimum element, then you swap its value with the head and then you remove the head.